# Update RecyclerView items or change Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have an `Activity` containing a `Fragment` which contains a `RecyclerView`. I have several Lists to toad into it:

- list 1: A, B, C
- list 2: D, E, F
- list 3: G, H, I, J
- list 4: K, L
- list 5: M, N, O, P, Q

For example, on clicking item A from *list1*, *list2* must be loaded; on clicking item B, *list3* must be loaded; on clicking either F or I from *lists 2 and 3*, *list5* must be loaded; and so on.

**Do you recommend me reloading/updating the `RecyclerView's Adapter` on each click and keep control of the Back button in order to show the previous list items, or shall I call a new Fragment instance for each list, (in my case above, 5 Fragments, one per list)???**

Comment: If all the lists consists of similar `itemview`, I see no need of even going with multiple Fragments. Just pass the list and notifyDataSetChanged. You can override the backbutton to load previous list and use an animation when data is loaded to provide a visible change when data is changed to improve the UX. Although, a single fragment can be instantiated multiple times but it will definitely make the process complex.

Comment: They are pretty similar, let's say I have two different itemView layouts